# ecs instances metadata files for EKS

Tags: metadata, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I know that in  Amazon ECS container agent by setting the variable `ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA=true` ecs metadata files are created for the containers.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-metadata.html

Is there any similar feature for the EKS?. I would like to retrieve instance metadata info from a file inside the container instead of using the IMDSv2 api.

Answer (score 0):

you simply can't, you still need to use IMDSv2 api in your service,if you want to have get instance metadata

if you're looking at the Pod Metadata, ref https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

or you can use pod labels too...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as far as know node labels are not inherited to pod information and there in an open feature request to kubernetes for it: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62078. So you cannot store them as env var. You can store node name and anything that already exists in pod information but not node labels. I hoped that there will be something like the ECS metadata file in EKS so to avoid the calls to IMDSv2 which can be unreliable sometimes.

Comment: I mean pod labels using downward api

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as part of the user data:

```
 "echo 'ECS_ENABLE_CONTAINER_METADATA=1' > /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
```

Found here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1514

Comment: Will that work for EKS containers too? To be honest after days of research I am not sure if my question is valid , probably Amazon does not support this and my only option is IMDS as @gumelaragum mentioned below.

Comment: I've not tested it, but it looks like that. I believe it should be easy to test, right, @SteveGr2015?
I've already added some user data for EC2 in a EKS cluster, so... I cannot find a reason for it to fail.